# Counter Strike 1.6 Map Development with Valve Hammer - Buy Menu Problem

Tags: language-agnostic

How to disable buying options in Counter Strike 1.6

I developed a map with Valve Hammer Tool and put some weapons on the floor now I want to "Turned Off" purchasing / buying menu options from my map, how is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about the editor but deleting the buyzone or moving it off the map would work I guess.

Comment: Yes, Thanks I just moved/hide my buy-zone into the ground where ct/t can't access. (Problem solved)